# DAX: Time Intelligence for custom Calendar

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to make Time Intelligence calculations when company has it's own custom Calendar (weeks are not ISO weeks, periods are like months, but don't match calendar months etc..)?

**Example: How to calculate in Power BI previous year week Amounts?**

Like `sameperiodlastyear` functionality, but for weeks (NOT months)

**Estimated result:**

[image]

**How I achieve this result using dirty trick:**

I created in Calendar table Last year DateKey Column: `LyDatekey = DateKey-1000` (in my case Datekey is in YYYYWWD)
And then created following measure:

```
MaxLyInventory = CALCULATE(prjMeasures[MaxInventory],USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar'[LyDateKey],SupplyData[DateKey]))
```

Why I don't like this:
Model should calculate next year forecast and next 2 years forecast - it means 3 additional `DataKey` columns in `Calendar` table and 3 additional connections per table in `Model` view - looks messy.

**What I tried (output available on screen below):**

1 Almost fine, but calculates wrong totals (returns `MAX` instead of `SUM`)

```
tmpMaxLyInventory = 
CALCULATE(
    [MaxInventory],
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar'), 
        'Calendar'[DateKey]=MAX(Calendar[DateKey])-1000
    )
)
```

2 Looks smart & beautiful, but doesn't work... ;)

```
2tmpMaxLyInventory = 
    VAR fltInventory =
        FILTER(
            SupplyData,
            SupplyData[PF Measure] = "Inventory"
            && RELATED('Calendar'[isWeekLastInPeriod])=TRUE() 
            && SupplyData[DateKey]=max(SupplyData[DateKey])-1000
        )     
    VAR t =
        SUMMARIZE(                        
                fltInventory,            
                SupplyData[DateKey],
                "tMaxInventory", SUM(SupplyData[PF Max Level])            
        )        
    RETURN
        SUMX(t,[tMaxInventory])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trick with `USERELATIONSHIP` is Ok!

To avoid this:

> Why I don't like this: Model should calculate next year forecast and
> next 2 years forecast - it means 3 additional DataKey columns in
> Calendar table and 3 additional connections per table in Model view -
> looks messy.

You could create additional "dummy" `Calendar` table with only one column - `DateKey` and use it between Calendar and Fact tables.

Then final result will look like this (Before and After):

```
vlmAct_LY1Weeks = 
    CALCULATE(
        [vlmAct],
        USERELATIONSHIP(routeCalendar[kYWD],'Calendar'[LY1W_kYWD])
    )
```

[image]

P.S. Probably in future `self joins` support will be imlemented - then no need for "dummy" table.